Movie in which Bruce Lee's character is played (used) as an inspirer & trainer?
I know this couldn't work better, but I definitely need some help. This movie is about an American college teenager who lost his parents in childhood. He loves Bruce Lee as his god. He often gets beaten up by some college guys. Then one day, while thinking about Bruce Lee, suddenly Bruce comes up to him [even though Bruce is dead according to that young man] like his hallucination & starts teaching him karate. Eventually, this young boy goes to a tournament & wins title match because of that training. 
In the meantime, I think, he comes to know that that all that Bruce's training is not true but his imagination because, at the end there is nothing about Bruce Lee except he goes to his parents' graveyard and feels like sharing with his parents which he also thinks, is a place of Bruce Lee's reminiscence.  
I didn't watch this movie, I know nothing more to this, regarding the film.
Please, can someone help me with the title of this film?

No Retreat, No Surrender, a movie that is remarkable perhaps for featuring a new actor named Jean Claude Van Damme as the villain :)
You can view the full movie here.
